# Sentiment Analysis - Emoticon

Tags: natural-language, sentiment-analysis, nltk

I am working on an NLP project, my objective is to compute a Sentiment Analysis over short text message.

So far, I did not come up with a solution to account the emoticons. I want to use a machine learning approach, but I also would like to include somehow the emoticons in the text for the analysis.
Most of the research papers I have read that imply a machine learning approach do not account for emoticons (instead, they just clean the text from all the special characters).
I only found lexicon based approaches that account for emoticons.

Any advised approach to include emoticons in my analysis?

Comment: I guess that the number of *commonly used* emoticons is pretty short, you could probably prepare a dictionary (emoticon -> sentiment) by hand and use it for your model.

Comment: If I create a dictionary for each emotion, such as
:) = Happy
:( = Sad 
... and so on, should I just replace the emoticon in the text with the word I've mapped it, and then compute the Sentiment Analysis?  Or you mean something else?

Comment: AFAIK, the software to classify sentiments assigns the sentiment labels to words, so you could simply treat your test with the software you're using and classify the emoticons using the dictionary and then join both results; or do as you suggested and "translate" the emoticons to sentiment-words that will be classified using your software.

Comment: This paper has a proposal for modeling emoticons... https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/68af/2d390b821a99b29f838fb57d2440ca3b3397.pdf

Comment: And this one: http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0144296 plus: http://kt.ijs.si/data/Emoji_sentiment_ranking/

Comment: Did you try incorporating emoticons to Bag of Words approach to use them as features?

Comment: A recent paper talks about how to combine the emoticons with text in Twitter Sentiment Analysis. Check this out: [Twitter Sentiment Analysis via Bi-sense Emoji Embedding and Attention-based LSTM](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.07961)